# Json unexpected token # at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have been working for hours trying to solve this. I have looked around and no one raises the issue when '#' is used in the error message.

It is my understanding that JSON.parse() takes a string then converts it to an object.

I have read in text fileLine and then split it where there are commas. I have then joined the necessary part of the data and then passed it in the method. it gives me the error above.

example data:

```
0,Lemons,lemons@gmauil.cpon,sppil,{"_root":{"data":0,"children":[{"data":{"filename":"gmsnet2.jpg","timeCreated":"2018-02-07","size":159},"children":[]},{"data":{"filename":"IMG_20160203_221955.jpg","timeCreated":"2018-02-07","size":3229224},"children":[]},{"data":{"filename":"Lemons","timeCreated":"-","size":"-"},"children":[{"data":{"filename":"hello","timeCreated":"-","size":"-"},"children":[{"data":{"filename":"IMG_20160205_193530.jpg","timeCreated":"2018-02-07","size":4115235},"children":[]},{"data":{"filename":"gmsnet2.jpg","timeCreated":"2018-02-07","size":159},"children":[]}]}]},{"data":{"filename":"dir2","timeCreated":"-","size":"-"},"children":[{"data":{"filename":"IMG_20160203_221955.jpg","timeCreated":"2018-02-07","size":3229224},"children":[]}]}]}}
```

reduced example of what is being passed:

```
{"_root":{"data":0,"children":[{"data":{"filename":"gmsnet2.jpg","timeCreated":"2018-02-07","size":159},"children":[]},{"data":{"filename":"IMG_20160203_221955.jpg","timeCreated":"2018-02-07","size":3229224},"children":[]}]}}
```

code that being used:

```
        var json = String(fileLine.split(',').slice(4).join(','));
        var rootdata = JSON.parse(json);
```

I have tested the JSON using JSONLint and it says it is valid json.
It works the first time this is called but when it is called the second time it crashes.

I debugged it and got:

`%7B%22_root%22%3A%7B%22data%22%3A0%2C%22children%22%3A%5B%7B%22data%22%3A%7B%22filename%22%3A%22gmsnet2.jpg%22%2C%22timeCreated%22%3A%222018-02-07%22%2C%22size%22%3A159%7D%2C%22children%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%7B%22data%22%3A%7B%22filename%22%3A%22IMG_20160203_221955.jpg%22%2C%22timeCreated%22%3A%222018-02-07%22%2C%22size%22%3A3229224%7D%2C%22children%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%7B%22data%22%3A%7B%22filename%22%3A%22Lemons%22%2C%22timeCreated%22%3A%22-%22%2C%22size%22%3A%22-%22%7D%2C%22children%22%3A%5B%7B%22data%22%3A%7B%22filename%22%3A%22hello%22%2C%22timeCreated%22%3A%22-%22%2C%22size%22%3A%22-%22%7D%2C%22children%22%3A%5B%7B%22data%22%3A%7B%22filename%22%3A%22IMG_20160205_193530.jpg%22%2C%22timeCreated%22%3A%222018-02-07%22%2C%22size%22%3A4115235%7D%2C%22children%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%2C%7B%22data%22%3A%7B%22filename%22%3A%22gmsnet2.jpg%22%2C%22timeCreated%22%3A%222018-02-07%22%2C%22size%22%3A159%7D%2C%22children%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22data%22%3A%7B%22filename%22%3A%22dir2%22%2C%22timeCreated%22%3A%22-%22%2C%22size%22%3A%22-%22%7D%2C%22children%22%3A%5B%7B%22data%22%3A%7B%22filename%22%3A%22IMG_20160203_221955.jpg%22%2C%22timeCreated%22%3A%222018-02-07%22%2C%22size%22%3A3229224%7D%2C%22children%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D%7D`

It would not print the second time.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: JSON.parse() takes a ***JSON*** string then converts it to an object

Comment: how do you consider this to be invalid?

Comment: With the data and code you've given it's impossible to debug... You must include a [***minimal***, complete, ***verifiable***, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code is not minimal because it includes Node filesystem methods which prevent it from being run in the browser as is, and it's not verifiable because [your existing code works](https://jsfiddle.net/Lecf176h/).

Comment: my guess is there are hidden characters in your string. debug it with `encodeURIComponent(json)`

Comment: So.... have you debugged it?  I mean if it works the first time, then the only thing that could cause it to break is a change in the parameter being fed to JSON.parse().  Either the json structure changed or a myriad of other issues.  Please debug and show us what the "**second**" value is that is coming.

Comment: There is your issue. Before you pass that parameter the second time, you need to run `decodeURIComponent(...);` on it to remove the HTML entity encodings. Otherwise, it is not JSON.

Comment: I tried this @War10ck but unfortunately the same error

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Your string is malformed. The inner double quotes are not properly escaped. They should all be displaying as `\"`. Where does this data come from?

Comment: @War10ck I have tried escaping the " however this means that it does not work the first time. the data is read in from a txt file. Also the error does not give a line number of the issue.